# Fail to read file - ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout

Tags: c#

It is a simple code but keep failing to read the Excel file. I used using statement before, thought mayeb using dispose before read but still same problem.

ReadTimeout = 'file.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

WriteTimeout = 'file.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

```
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\test\source\repos\MnMC\MnMC\wwwroot\CFolder\PBot\Files\Incidents\PBot_Incident.xlsx";
        var builder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = "Incident Report." };
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                builder.Attachments.Add("PBot_Incident.xlsx", memoryStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: grant read write permission to your exe file or run it as admin or grant admin read write permission to ur excel file.

Comment: Those "errors" are merely debugger notifications, MemoryStream doesn't implement timeouts.  You'll have to focus on writing correct code, insert memoryStream.Position = 0; after the CopyTo() call.  And you must use the *using* statement so the file is closed properly.

Comment: Thank you Hans, It worked as soon as i used position = 0.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant said, ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout werent cause the problem. As soon as i set memoryStream.Position = 0. it solve the problem.